# While Loop Not Iterating Correctly

Tags: c, networking, loops, while-loop, protocols

I'm working on a computer networks project to simulate the TCp/IP model and I'm having a really weird issue. It's pretty simple, but I just can't figure out what's wrong with my code. Inside my transmit function below I have a while loop that is collecting separate frames into a buffer that is cleared each time I go to collect a new frame. The problem is that the while loop is collecting 1 extra variable from the next frame into the previous frame. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
void transmit(char *ipaddress){
char mode;
char *ap = calloc(MAX, sizeof(char));   //Arrays used to transfer data from each layer
char *Frame = calloc(MAX, sizeof(char));
mode = 's';
int i = 0, k = 0, j = 0;
ap = layer4(ap);    //Each layer returns data that is stored
ap = layer3(ap, ipaddress); 
ap = layer2(ap);
k = strlen(ap);
printf(" APLENGTH %d", k);

while(k >= 0){     //This is where I start collecting frames
        memset(Frame,0,strlen(Frame));
        while(ap[i] != 3 && ap[i+1] != 2){ //Stop if ETX followed by STX
        Frame[i] = ap[j]; 
//printf("%d, Frame[%d]: %c",j,i,Frame[i]); This was for debugging. 
        i++; j++; 
        k--; //Decrement the amount of characters left in the total package 
    }
    Frame[i] = ap[j]; //Append the last ETX bit to complete frame 
//  printf("\n"); 
    //printf("%d, Frame[%d]: %c",j,i,Frame[i]);
    i++,j++;
    Frame[i] = '\0'; //Append terminate character
    //      printf("%d, Frame[%d]: %c",j,i,Frame[i]);

    i = layer1(Frame, mode);
        printf("FRAME: %s\n\n",Frame);
    if(i != 0){
        printf("Terminating Program");
        exit(1); }
        i = 0;
}

//ap = layer1(ap, mode);

} //Trasmit Layer
```

Here is the output I get:

FRAME: STX102000000000127.0.0.1000000000000000abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcd1eb5ETX

FRAME: STX101010000000127.0.0.1000000000000000efghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghi1f1bETXSTX

FRAME: 101020000000127.0.0.1000000000000000jklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmn1f35ETXSTX0

FRAME: 85031000000127.0.0.1000000000000000opqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzab
184aETX

The first frame is fine. The second frame should not have an STX on the end. The third frame should not have STX and 0 on the end. The fourth frame should have a STX and 0 on the front :/

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is `1`.

Comment: I believe this `while(k >= 0)` should be `while(k > 0)` otherwise you will do one extra iteration.

Comment: Yeah, I thought it may have been that to, but it didn't have any affect when I changed it to "while( k>0 );"

Answer (score 2):

To everyone saying that k>0 is his problem, that may be right but it's not his main problem. His problem is occurring even when k>0 as he said that it occurs BETWEEN frames. As soon as the last frame is transmitted then that's when the k>0 loop comes in effect. It has to do with the inner while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Its probably this loop:

```
k = strlen(ap);

while(k >= 0){     //This is where I start collecting frames
    ...
    k--; //Decrement the amount of characters left in the total package 
}
```

Notice that it goes from length down to and including 0. That's length+1 times through the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your while condition by the below one :

```
while(k > 0)
```